# run function on jquery.html added element (with fiddle)

Tags: jquery, html

I have added an element using jquery.html but I can't seem to run another function on that element?? Any ideas

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0j50L4uo/1/) http://jsfiddle.net/0j50L4uo/1/

```
<a class="trigger">Cick here A</a>
<br/><br/>
<div id="test"></div>

$(".trigger").click(function() {
    alert( "click" );

});

$('#test').html('<a class="trigger">Click here B</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`click()` function won't listen to dynamically created elements.

Use `on()` function (event delegation) in order to attach event listeners to dynamically added elements:

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0j50L4uo/2/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.trigger', function() { 
  // ... 
});
```